# iPhone Web based apllication back ,forward and refresh button

Tags: html, ios4

In my iphone web based application i want to add backword,Forward,Refresh and Action button like the native Webview,How i implement this in my app.

Thanks,

Arun

Answer (score 0):

Use what HTML gives you to draw this navigation. Or look for [ready code](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-19512_7-10114978-233.html) for that.

Comment: ,Actually i want to open like google in <a> tag and want to record the navigation back,forward and refresh all things like natively.